# How good is Altova MapForce

Tags: mapping, edi, altova, x12

My company needs to convert X12 5010 837 files into our database and back out. The tool we have been playing around with is Altova MapForce (trial). I have been trying to check references but Altova hasn't been quite helpful in that regard. The CNET reviews for it got me a bit concerned. I've searched quite a bit on stackoverflow to see whether anyone has any feedback on it, but most of what I found is Q&A on particular functions and How Tos.

I would greatly appreciate if one of you who has purchased Mapforce and implemented at least one project or solution with it can share what you found good and bad about it?

Is it a solid tool that can process about 30K-50K claims a year? Will it crash everyday like some of the CNET reviews state?

Just e-mail me if you would rather chat over the phone about it.

Regards,

Andrew R

Comment: What is your budget?  A $1000 tool, you're gonna get what you pay for.  Do you have a requirement to build the "transform" into a larger application?  That has always been the sticking point for me:  build the map and then insert generated code into a larger framework.  I'd rather just have a self-standing engine that does the translation / communication. That's just my opinion.  I prefer traditional integration frameworks like Liaison, Sterling, Extol, etc. Altova's XML Spy application is the bomb though.

Answer (score 1):

The tool is very reliable, easy to use.  One of the nice things is that there is full error enumeration of the X12 library, Altova is one of two tools vendors for X12.org

It is reliable. My suggestion is to do the transformation and then use refactoring to manage the code generated in C# or Java so you can update the maps very easily by just copying the generated code into an existing directory within a project.  I would not modify Altova code, they suggest that you do not in their documentation, but don't go into the issue of refactoring by extracting a method and changing namespace

If you have worked with other X12 tools, Sterling Commerce or IBM Gentran, Biztalk, Informatica, etc.. you will appreciate the simplicity of the tool and the value.  If you have no experience with EDI you are at the mercy of the opinions of others who have no experience with EDI who actually integrate

On a 1-10 I give the product a 9 and within the right architecture, pruned of enumeration is preferable to the other stated technologies mentioned, give me some Linux, Lamp, JBOSS?? and Java refactored and I have the solution

Answer (score -4):

It's is really nice tool.

I was work on Altova Mapforce one year.Best thing with Altova mapforce is,
You need to work on Altova mapforce. They are not giving you ready to eat food. 
You need to customize Altova mapforce SP directory as per your requirement.
Altova mapforce auto generate code take care your all validations of database.
You can validate your single record for table.

I was very happy to work with altova mapforce. But need to patience with learning.
One more thing.. IT support is very nice.